# passwords memory test versus passwords test memory

Tags: meaning

Many letters...

English is largely accurate and analytical language, there is a word order, in contrast to Russian (we are talking about nouns and adjectives, I'm not talking about verbs now). Many people think that "passwords memory test" is a standard form, because each dependent word is located to the left of its main word.

This “rule” has an exception: dependent words with their own prepositions are placed to the right of the main one. This is necessary to avoid confusion and to show different meanings. For example: the largest building in the town (the largest town building) versus the largest in the town building. This is understandable, but the "passwords test memory" has no prepositions, and you can paste it into Google and you will see that it is used by well-known media quite often. What is my question: are "passwords memory test" and "passwords test memory" absolutely identical forms or the second has some stylistic coloring? But when a native speaker reversed the words in this construction, did he mean something consciously / unconsciously?

I started learning English recently, before that I studied Chinese, but my native language is Russian. There are many grammar books on the Internet, but little about syntax. Maybe someone knows good books specifically on the syntax and style of English (preferably in Russian or English)?

Comment: They mean very different things.  “Passwords test memory” means that memory is tested by passwords.  “Passwords memory test” would be a type of test- perhaps a test of memory using passwords, or a test of passwords memory (the memory where passwords are stored)

Comment: Lacks clarity.  Rather than putting up a wall of words, give some examples of the usage you have in mind.

Comment: In *passwords memory test*, you have a three-word noun; in *passwords test memory*, you have a subject, a verb, and a noun. The second version could as easily be *some people on a game show test [their] memory.* Unfortunately, the only way to know this is from experience and context. Switching the location of three similar words might not change the meaning so drastically. The problem, for one, is that *test* is both a noun and a verb.

Comment: Even as a three-word noun, *passwords memory test* is likely parsed as either *passwords-memory test* (a memory test of passwords) or *passwords memory- test* (a test of password memory). In either case, neither *passwords-test memory* nor *passwords test-memory* would mean the same thing. By switching the words, you change the meaning of the phrase no matter how you parse it.